# How can I create a python function to calculate spreads across panel data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, panel

I have a set of panel data that contains different bonds and the bond yields yields across multiple days.

I would like to create a function which, for a given day, takes two bonds and calculates the spread, and then does this for every bond pair, for every day.

The resulting dataframe will have the date, a column indicating which two bonds and then the yield spread.

Original dataframe:

```
data1 = {'Date':['26/10/2019', '26/10/2019', '26/10/2019', '26/10/2019', '25/10/2019', '25/10/2019', '25/10/2019', 
                '25/10/2019'],
        'Bond':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Yield':[1.1, 1.11, 1.2, 1.3, 1, 1.1, 1.25, 1.29]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
data2 = {'Date':['26/10/2019', '26/10/2019', '26/10/2019', '26/10/2019','26/10/2019','26/10/2019', '25/10/2019', 
                '25/10/2019', '25/10/2019', '25/10/2019','25/10/2019','25/10/2019'],
        'Bond':['BA', 'CB', 'CA', 'DC', 'DB', 'DA', 'BA', 'CB', 'CA', 'DC', 'DB', 'DA'],
        'Yield':[0.01, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.19, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.04, 0.19, 0.29]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain 1. what's a spread means? 2. how did you get for 0.01 for `BA` on `26/10/2019`?

Comment: Thank you! - spread is the difference between the yields. For BA, 0.01 = yield(B) - yield(A) = 1.11-1.1

Answer (score 2):

First we [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on date to get all the combinations of the `bonds` next to each other.

Then we [`drop duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) while sorting ([`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)) on the bonds, because `AB` is the same as `BA` and `CD` is the same as `DC`.

Then finally we [`substract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) the `yields` from each other and take the absolute:

```
mrg = df1.merge(df1, on='Date').query('Bond_x != Bond_y')
mrg.loc[:, ['Bond_x', 'Bond_y']] = np.sort(mrg.loc[:, ['Bond_x', 'Bond_y']])
mrg = mrg.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date','Bond_x', 'Bond_y'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': mrg['Date'],
                   'Bond': mrg['Bond_x'].str.cat(mrg['Bond_y']),
                   'Yield': mrg['Yield_x'].sub(mrg['Yield_y']).abs()}).reset_index(drop=True)

          Date Bond  Yield
0   26/10/2019   AB   0.01
1   26/10/2019   AC   0.10
2   26/10/2019   AD   0.20
3   26/10/2019   BC   0.09
4   26/10/2019   BD   0.19
5   26/10/2019   CD   0.10
6   25/10/2019   AB   0.10
7   25/10/2019   AC   0.25
8   25/10/2019   AD   0.29
9   25/10/2019   BC   0.15
10  25/10/2019   BD   0.19
11  25/10/2019   CD   0.04
```